# jquery get values from table from two columns at the same time to operate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm struggling trying to perform the following operation:

I've this table:

```
  <table id="saleDetails" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code </th>
        <th>Description </th>
        <th>Price </th>
        <th>Quantity </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th> 001 </th>
        <th> One description </th>
        <th> 30.5 </th>
        <th> <input type="number"></input> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> 002 </th>
        <th> Some description </th>
        <th> 120 </th>
        <th> <input type="number"></input> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> 003 </th>
        <th> Other description </th>
        <th> 300.5 </th>
        <th> <input type="number"></input> </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

what i'm trying to do is get the unitPrice and multiply it by the quantity input value to get the subtotal for each line.

i got the unitPrice with this sentence for each cell in column 3:

```
$('#saleDetails tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
  console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

but i would like to perform the operation unitPrice * quantity (quantity is a input component) and i'm not sure how get the unitPrice and quantity at the same time (I'm not sure if that's possible) for each iteration on the table.

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#saleDetails tr').each(function () {
    var price = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text()
    var quantity = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4) input").val()
    console.log( quantity + "   " + price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM traversal method to target the `input`. Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `TR` element the use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the `input`

```
$('#saleDetails tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
    console.log( $(this).text(), quantity );
});
```

```js
$('#saleDetails tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
  var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
  console.log($(this).text().trim(), quantity);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="saleDetails" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code </th>
      <th>Description </th>
      <th>Price </th>
      <th>Quantity </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 001 </td>
      <td> One description </td>
      <td> 30.5 </td>
      <td> <input type="number" value="5" /></d>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are various method, you can also use

```
var quantity = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code by using class selector; [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkztk7m5/)

html:

```
<table id="saleDetails" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code </th>
        <th>Description </th>
        <th>Price </th>
        <th>Quantity </th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> 001 </td>
        <td> One description </td>
        <td class="unitprice"> 30.5 </td>
        <td> <input type="number" class="quantity" /> </td>
        <td class="total"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 002 </td>
        <td> Some description </td>
        <td class="unitprice"> 120 </td>
        <td> <input type="number" class="quantity" /> </td>
        <td class="total"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and js:

```
$('#saleDetails tr').on("change", ".quantity", function (event) {

    var $row = $(event.delegateTarget);

    var price = $row.find(".unitprice").text();
    var quantity = $row.find(".quantity").val();
    var total = price*quantity;

    $row.find(".total").text(total);
});
```

Comment: Hi, this is pretty good too. question: variable total is getting NaN object. should i parse price and quantity to number?